# FileField() Error when trying to upload file using GAE and Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Hello Stack Overflow community!!

I am attempting to upload a file to GAE and I'm using Django. When I run the following code it returns this error:

```
Tried upload in module pathway.app.views. 
Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'FileField'
```

When googling for a solution I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/6e9ee27c1e6a8539), but this issue should have 
been fixed by now right?

I am not sure at this point what I have done wrong, I am new to GAE,python and Django so any help would be appreciated!

And if anyone has a better solution to this problem, please tell me. Seems too much code for such a simple task.

models.py

```
class UploadModel(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    file = db.BlobProperty()

    blobl = db.BlobProperty()

    modified_on = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add= 1)
    modified_by = db.UserProperty()
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
     form = form.UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(models.db.Blob(request.FILES['file']))
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
else:
     form = form.UploadFileForm()

files = models.UploadModel.all().order('-modified_on').fetch(20)
payload = dict(files = files)
return render("upload.html",payload)
```

form.py

```
from django import newforms as forms import models

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField()
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Django? GAE has supported Django 1.1 since 2009.

Comment: I dont believe I am using an old version. What I think I may have done was look into old sample code. You know of a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the version of Django included with Google App Engine, 0.96.4, which is four years old and comes from before the `newforms` library included support for file fields (and before it was renamed to simply `forms`).

Install an up-to-date Django version in your GAE project's directory and use that instead.

Comment: Django is up to date. I believe I have looked into very old sample code. Do you know the right import? Or were I can find the documentation?

Comment: Sorry, if you're doing `from django import newforms` without an error there, then you are using an old version. Newforms was renamed to forms at version 1.0.

Comment: It still gives me the same erros using just "from django import forms"

Comment: By running the command django.VERSION on the python console it returns, "(1, 2, 4, 'final', 0)". Isn't this the latest version?